# Error from install angular-translate-loader-static-files

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angular-translate

i want to install  `angular-translate-loader-static-files`
but when i run this command line `bower install angular-translate-loader-static-files`

I found this error :

```
node.js:844
    var cwd = process.cwd();
                      ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
    at Function.startup.resolveArgv0 (node.js:844:23)
    at startup (node.js:58:13)
    at node.js:935:3
```

please what's this error and how to resolve it

Comment: do you get same error if simply running $ node im console?

Comment: yes ,i have always this error

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ cd $PWD; node server.js
```

> From your comment:

Try deleting modules and reinstalling:

```
$ rm -fr node_modules

$ npm i
```

Comment: i found this error:(module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/binov1/workElolinkMobile/HelloLink/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:935:3)